# NSMutableArray elements not being released in dealloc

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray

I have define a NSMutableArray in .h file

```
NSMutableArray *arrayBatLevel;
```

init it in .m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self DataTimer];
}

-(void)DataTimer
{
    [recordDataTimer invalidate];
    recordDataTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:[timeInterval.text floatValue]
                                                       target:self
                                                     selector:@selector(recordData)
                                                     userInfo:nil
                                                      repeats:YES];
}

-(void)recordData
{
    if ([aSwitch isOn] == YES) {
        if (arrayBatLevel == nil) {
            arrayBatLevel = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            NSLog(@"alloc arrayBatLevel");
        }

        [arrayBatLevel addObject:batLevel.text];
    }
}
```

and release in dealloc

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [arrayBatLevel release];   
    [super dealloc];
}
```

but, it seems it’s not releasing all the objects inside the `NSMutableArray`.
When I exit this app and run it gain, these objects still in NSMutableArray, why?

Comment: Sorry can you be more precise. From what I could understand, You will be running the app again and go through the same process again, so wont you be creating the array again?

Comment: Are you sure you are exiting the app? Going back to the home screen will send your app to the background, not exit it.

Comment: ya, I click "Home" button to exit app and click app again, NSMutableArray's objects have not release....

Comment: Clicking the Home button no longer exits the app (unless set explicitly in the Info.plist), so dealloc isn't called. The app is just 'paused' in its current state and is resumed when you tap the icon again.

Comment: I don't want to "paused", I want to exit the app and remove all objects of nsmutablearray, so... How to "exit" app? btw, why dealloc can not be called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not with the array, it's with the objects inside the array.  You don't indicate where "batLevel" came from.  I'm guessing that "batLevel" is retained somewhere else, and with it "batLevel.text".